# Install Raspbian to SSD with existing OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, external-hdd

I have an SSD which I previously installed a Raspberry Pi image of NextcloudPi.

It works fine, but I would like to switch to Raspbian now.

Preparing to install raspbian to the SSD using the rpi-imager, I cannot find the SSD the list of storage options, nor in the list of disks in Nautilus.

The Rpi has no problem booting from the SSD, but connecting to another computer yields no response.

The SSD is connected to my laptop using a USB-SATA cable.

It worked when I first purchased the SSD, but now that there is an OS on it, I can't access it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can ***zero out*** the GPT or MBR partition table at the front of the disk using the `dd` command.   Where X is your drive  `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd`

**BE CAREFUL! Verify and KNOW what you are doing.** You have been warned.  `umount /dev/sdX`   un mount the disk before using the `dd` command (AKA "data duplicator" or "disk destroyer").

- `fdisk -l`    list the partition tables on all the devices
- `df -h`   which disks are mounted and what size free space available
- `gdisk  print`
- `sgdisk  ????`
- `sfdisk`

Links:

- [Explanation of sgdisk and sfdisk, parted](https://www.pozzo-balbi.com/help/Fdisk_/_gdisk_/_sfdisk_/_sgdisk_/_parted)
- [Rod Smiths sgdisk walk through](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk-walkthrough.html)
- [InfoTinks explanation of writing partition tables to disk](http://www.infotinks.com/writing-new-partition-tables-via-sgdisk-gpt-and-sfdisk-mbr/)

`dd  if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 conv=sync count=34`
fills the partition table with zeros so that you can see it as empty.

[gparted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) is great for making a new partition or resizing an existing partition.

**[puppylinux.com](https://puppylinux.com)**  all puppys have  gparted installed as an application to use.   So download puppylinux.com  .ISO file and use etcher.io or `dd` command to write the file to the USB flash drive.  Boot from the USB flash drive and then you will have access to 'gparted' application.  Nice to have a bootable PuppyLinux on a USB flash drive in case of an emergency laying in your computer desk drawer.   Gparted will show you what is in the partition table on that disk.  You did not say what tool you tried to use.  `parted` is good, too. Gparted is built using `parted`.